# android: format textview

Tags: android, textview

is it possible to format a textview for a widget so that it looks like the text below the apps.

like in this screenshot:

[image]

i am looking for the exact textcolor, the exact dropshadow and the rounded background.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, check with the [source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher2.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/launcher2/BubbleTextView.java;h=4a56e1bb0dee320fd25ab71d73b587155cebda63;hb=HEAD), which shows that Android is using a custom TextView to implement the bubbled background around the text.

It appears that the text itself is styled using styles in the launcher app:

```
<style name="WorkspaceIcon">
    <item name="android:textSize">13dip</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#FF000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2.0</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/shortcut_selector</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">5dip</item>
</style>

<style name="WorkspaceIcon.Portrait">
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">5dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">4dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">3dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">3dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">13dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">8dip</item>
</style>

<style name="WorkspaceIcon.Landscape">
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">3dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">2dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dip</item>
</style>
```

Those styles are called from the launcher's layouts as appropriate.

Comment: thanks. it seems there is no access to this custom textview via the android sdk, right?

Comment: right, but you should be able to drop BubbleTextView straight into your project.